# Drawing from a multivariate t-student in matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, distribution

I'm trying to draw random numbers from a multivariate t-student distribution (with a specified mean, variance and df) in Matlab.

Looking into the matlab documentation, I've found the "mvtrnd" function (http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/stats/mvtrnd.html), but unfortunately, it returns values centered in 0.

Could you suggest me any other function or approach to solve my problem?

EDIT:

I think I have solved the problem writing the function below. I have found in wikipedia that if X is distributed as a multivariate t-student (mu, $$\Sigma$$, df) and Y as a multivariate normal (0, $$\Sigma$$), than $$X = \mu + Y * \sqrt{\frac{df}{\chi^2_{df}}}$$.

```
function [ output ] = st_rndmvt( mu, sigma, df, cases )
    if nargin < 4
        cases = 1;
    end

    mu = mu(:)';
    output = zeros(cases, length(mu));

    for i=1:cases
        output(i, :) = mu + mvnrnd(zeros(length(sigma), 1), sigma) * sqrt(df/chi2rnd(df));
    end
end
```

Comment: For mean mu and standard derivation s, it should be `mu+s.*mvtrnd(parameters)`, but I don't know if the covariance matrix must be rescaled.